# If checkbox is check and has value do something

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

First of (like always) thanks for the time to read my question. I'm trying to write a simple jQuery script that shows a `element` when it's `checked` and hides this `element` when it's not checked. I've searched around the forums here, and there's a lot of questions like mine. But non seemed to work for me.

Here is the HTML:

```
<li class="sf-level-0 sf-item-20" data-sf-count="38" data-sf-depth="0">
    <input class="sf-input-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="spelmaker" name="_sft_functie[]" id="sf-input-6cf65fe1fd48f4322e62b46c3ac4219b">
    <label class="sf-label-checkbox" for="sf-input-6cf65fe1fd48f4322e62b46c3ac4219b">Spelmaker<span class="sf-count">(38)</span></label>
</li>
<li class="sf-level-0 sf-item-27" data-sf-count="9" data-sf-depth="0">
    <input class="sf-input-checkbox guideLinr-element-highlight" type="checkbox" value="spelmaker" name="_sft_functie[]" id="sf-input-95c8e5259c89324d9b3c9495b808f0a6">
    <label class="sf-label-checkbox" for="sf-input-95c8e5259c89324d9b3c9495b808f0a6">Workshop<span class="sf-count">(9)</span></label>
</li>
```

Here is my script:

```
if($(".sf-input-checkbox").val('spelmaker').is(':checked'))
    $('.sf-field-post-meta-type_workshop').hide();
else
   $('.sf-field-post-meta-type_workshop').show();
```

This works, for some reason. BUT only on the element with value `spelmaker`. So I thought I did something wrong. Then I checked the inspector and **all** my `li input` elements have the `value` `spelmaker` now.

What I really want is to have the following:

HTML:

```
<li class="sf-level-0 sf-item-20" data-sf-count="38" data-sf-depth="0">
    <input class="sf-input-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="spelmaker" name="_sft_functie[]" id="sf-input-6cf65fe1fd48f4322e62b46c3ac4219b">
    <label class="sf-label-checkbox" for="sf-input-6cf65fe1fd48f4322e62b46c3ac4219b">Spelmaker<span class="sf-count">(38)</span></label>
</li>
<li class="sf-level-0 sf-item-27" data-sf-count="9" data-sf-depth="0">
    <input class="sf-input-checkbox guideLinr-element-highlight" type="checkbox" value="workshop" name="_sft_functie[]" id="sf-input-95c8e5259c89324d9b3c9495b808f0a6">
    <label class="sf-label-checkbox" for="sf-input-95c8e5259c89324d9b3c9495b808f0a6">Workshop<span class="sf-count">(9)</span></label>
</li>
```

SCRIPT:

```
if($(".sf-input-checkbox").**WITH**->val('spelmaker').is(':checked'))
    $('.sf-field-post-meta-type_workshop').hide();
else
    $('.sf-field-post-meta-type_workshop').show();
```

AND:

```
if($(".sf-input-checkbox").**WITH**->val('workshop').is(':checked'))
        $('.sf-field-post-meta-type_spelmaker').hide();
    else
        $('.sf-field-post-meta-type_spelmaker').show();
```

Anyone that has a snippet or something that would help me? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might help you.

Iterate every the checkboxs and control whether check or not. And get target div using `$(".sf-field-post-meta-type_"+$(this).val())`. This check only one when initialize.

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(){
    if(this.checked){
       $(".sf-field-post-meta-type_"+$(this).val()).hide();
    }else {
       $(".sf-field-post-meta-type_"+$(this).val()).show();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<li class="sf-level-0 sf-item-20" data-sf-count="38" data-sf-depth="0">
    <input class="sf-input-checkbox" type="checkbox"  value="spelmaker" name="_sft_functie[]" id="sf-input-6cf65fe1fd48f4322e62b46c3ac4219b">
    <label class="sf-label-checkbox" for="sf-input-6cf65fe1fd48f4322e62b46c3ac4219b">Spelmaker<span class="sf-count">(38)</span></label>
</li>
<li class="sf-level-0 sf-item-27" data-sf-count="9" data-sf-depth="0">
    <input class="sf-input-checkbox guideLinr-element-highlight" type="checkbox" checked value="workshop" name="_sft_functie[]" id="sf-input-95c8e5259c89324d9b3c9495b808f0a6">
    <label class="sf-label-checkbox" for="sf-input-95c8e5259c89324d9b3c9495b808f0a6">Workshop<span class="sf-count">(9)</span></label>
</li>

<div class="sf-field-post-meta-type_spelmaker">
type_spelmaker
</div>
<div class="sf-field-post-meta-type_workshop">
type_workshop
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As I could understand you want to get the currently clicked value.

In that case I would pick the `click()` function using jQuery

Example

```js
// So we check on checkbox on click
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on("click", function() {  
    // Here we check wheter checkbox is checked
    // So we don't get anything back on unclick
    // We use $(this) because we want the current checked checkboxs information
    if($(this).is(":checked")){
      // This will return the currently clicked checkbox value 
      var val = $(this).val();
      
      //Now we can do the check if the value is spelmaker
      if(val === "spelmaker"){
        console.log("You picked spelmaker");
      } else {
        console.log("Why did you NOT pick spelmaker");
      }
      
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="sf-level-0 sf-item-20" data-sf-count="38" data-sf-depth="0">
    <input class="sf-input-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="spelmaker" name="_sft_functie[]" id="sf-input-6cf65fe1fd48f4322e62b46c3ac4219b">
    <label class="sf-label-checkbox" for="sf-input-6cf65fe1fd48f4322e62b46c3ac4219b">Spelmaker<span class="sf-count">(38)</span></label>
</li>
<li class="sf-level-0 sf-item-27" data-sf-count="9" data-sf-depth="0">
    <input class="sf-input-checkbox guideLinr-element-highlight" type="checkbox" value="workshop" name="_sft_functie[]" id="sf-input-95c8e5259c89324d9b3c9495b808f0a6">
    <label class="sf-label-checkbox" for="sf-input-95c8e5259c89324d9b3c9495b808f0a6">Workshop<span class="sf-count">(9)</span></label>
</li>
```

This example is based on just having "spelmaker" is or is not checked based on click.

Answer (score 1):

> Check working snippet below. hope its helpfull for you

This Example is behalf of value `checked` and `uncheked`

```js
$(document).ready(function () {


$(".sf-input-checkbox").change(function(){
//var  checkVal = $(".sf-input-checkbox:checked").val();
 var val =$(this).val();
  if(this.checked){
  if(val == "spelmaker"){
  $(".sf-field-post-meta-type_spelmaker").show();
  }
  
  else if(val == "workshop"){
  $(".sf-field-post-meta-type_workshop").show();
  
  }
  }
  else{
  if(val == "spelmaker"){
  $(".sf-field-post-meta-type_spelmaker").hide();
 
  }
  
  else if(val == "workshop"){
  $(".sf-field-post-meta-type_workshop").hide();
 
  
  }
  }
  
  
  
});

});
```

```css
.sf-field-post-meta-type_spelmaker{
min-height:100px;
background:red;
display:none;
}
.sf-field-post-meta-type_workshop{
min-height:100px;
background:green;
display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li class="sf-level-0 sf-item-20" data-sf-count="38" data-sf-depth="0">
    <input class="sf-input-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="spelmaker" name="_sft_functie[]" id="sf-input-6cf65fe1fd48f4322e62b46c3ac4219b">
    <label class="sf-label-checkbox" for="sf-input-6cf65fe1fd48f4322e62b46c3ac4219b">Spelmaker<span class="sf-count">(38)</span></label>
</li>
<li class="sf-level-0 sf-item-27" data-sf-count="9" data-sf-depth="0">
    <input class="sf-input-checkbox guideLinr-element-highlight" type="checkbox" value="workshop" name="_sft_functie[]" id="sf-input-95c8e5259c89324d9b3c9495b808f0a6">
    <label class="sf-label-checkbox" for="sf-input-95c8e5259c89324d9b3c9495b808f0a6">Workshop<span class="sf-count">(9)</span></label>
</li>
</ul>
<div class="sf-field-post-meta-type_spelmaker">spelmaker</div>
<div class="sf-field-post-meta-type_workshop">workshop</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with an example solution https://jsfiddle.net/tbL6vuyp/

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
 $('div').toggle();
});
```

```css
div{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: blue;
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" />Try me!!!

<br/>
<br/>

<div>

</div>
```

I have used **jQuery Toggle** instead of **hide / show**

Comment: How do I target the specific values with this code?